# Segfault using std::shared_ptr during destruction likely due to too many function calls on the stack

Tags: c++, c++11

The following code compiles and runs fine:

```
#include <memory>
struct MyTree {
    std::shared_ptr <MyTree> left;
    std::shared_ptr <MyTree> right;
    int val;
    MyTree(
        std::shared_ptr <MyTree> left_,
        std::shared_ptr <MyTree> right_,
        int val_
    ) : left(left_), right(right_), val(val_) {};
};
int main() {
    std::shared_ptr <MyTree> t(
        new MyTree( std::shared_ptr <MyTree>(),
                    std::shared_ptr <MyTree>(),
                    0)
    );  
    for(int i=0;i<10000;i++) {
        t.reset(new MyTree(t,t,0));
    }
}
```

However, when the for loop is changed from 10000 to 100000, I receive a segfault.  Looking at the result in gdb, it looks like the destructors being called as a result of the garbage collection in std::shared_ptr create a backtrace that's thousands deep.  As such, I think the segfault is due to running out of room on the stack from the function calls.  I've two questions.  First, is this a correct assessment of the segfault?  Second, if so, is there a good way to manage custom data structures such as trees that need to be garbage collected, but may be extremely large.  Thanks.

Comment: There is no garbage collection in C++.

Comment: @JohnDibling I am pretty sure the OP understands that automatic GC like in Java and other languages does not exist in C++, I think he means the recursive deallocation that is needed in such a case due to shared_ptr detruction

Comment: @JohnDibling: std::shared_ptr does simple reference counting garbage collection.  That's what I'm talking about.

Comment: @JohnDibling: What would you call the job performed by `std::shared_ptr` and `std::unique_ptr`, then?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit:  Not garbage collection.

Comment: @JohnDibling: And why's that then?

Comment: shared_ptr doesn't only do just that, shared_ptr is one of the most expensive smart pointers. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr also i can't see the point of this design where shared_ptr are inside the object and there are 2 different shared_ptr per object, it's a waste of space.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, becasue `shared_ptr` is not capable of resolving cyclic references which OP has plenty of here.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit:  Because GC is automatic in the sense that the programmer does not have direct control over when objects are destroyed and the memory is reclaimed.  `shared_ptr`, `unique_ptr` and their ilk are manual in that the object is destroyed at the call site when the smart ptr goes out of scope and the object dtor is called.

Comment: @aleguna: What cycles?  This isn't a doubly-linked list, it's a binary tree.  All the pointers are directed in the same direction, which is *deeper into the tree, away from the root*.

Comment: @JohnDibling: Only in your incredibly narrow personal definition of "garbage collection". In fact reference counting is considered a garbage collection algorithm by everybody else.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit:  OK.  I hope you feel better now.

Comment: @aleguna: No definition of "garbage collection" that I've ever seen names cycle detection as a prerequisite; in fact plenty of real garbage collectors throughout history have failed in such cases. This isn't even one of them!

Comment: @JohnDibling: What do you mean? You seem to have changed topic somewhat from the discussion over whether `std::shared_ptr` counts as "garbage collection" in that I don't understand the relevance of my "feelings"...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit:  What I mean is it seems clear to me that your intent on engaging me in this conversation was not to have a reasonable discussion about it, but to simply show that I'm wrong.  Using devices such as claiming that "everybody else" agrees with you does not lead to a civil debate.  So, you win, I yield, and I hope that if something put you in a foul mood to try to go down this road with me, I hope you feel better now.

Comment: @JohnDibling: If the conclusion of the discussion is that you are shown to be wrong then that is beyond my control, I'm afraid. I can assure you that I am not on some vendetta, out to "get you". Please try to accept the possibility that you may be incorrect, without resorting to this emotional blubbery! Check out these peer-reviewed references from famous scientific journals: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting#References; the established definition of "garbage collection" includes reference-counting mechanisms such as `std::shared_ptr` and _that_ is what I've intended to show.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit:  That article is about ref counting, and the only connection made to GC in that article is to say that some implementations of GC use ref counting.  That does not mean that everything that uses ref counting is garbage collection.  Bjarne Stroustrup [does not agree](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq.html#garbage-collection) with your "established definition".  Nor does the Std Comittee, else why would they have provided for a garbage collection ABI in C++11?

Comment: @JohnDibling: I did not link to the article - I linked to the journals it references. They make for a good read. As for Bjarne, well he disagrees with many things and is certainly within his rights to do so, as are you.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit:  On the topic of [Garbage Collection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)), wiki says that, "Garbage collection is often portrayed as the opposite of manual memory management, which requires the programmer to specify which objects to deallocate and return to the memory system."  Using `shared_ptr` etc, the C++ programmer specifies when and where an object is to be destroyed, hence `shared_ptr` doesn't meet wiki's definition of garbage collection.

Comment: BTW see the related A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168821/stdunique-ptr-as-pointer-in-a-node-based-structure basically AFAIK you can get away with linked list, but not for the trees...

Comment: @wyer33: You are creating a tree with (conceptually) `pow(2, 100000)` nodes. It is only because each node's left and right sub-tree are identical and shared that you can fit it in memory in the first place. Before you worry about the stack depth, see how far you get with constructing a real tree (each node has different data and/or sub-trees)

Comment: @JohnDibling: That exact article also has [an entire chapter on Reference Counting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29#Reference_counting) which states "Reference counting is a form of garbage collection" then explicitly discusses C++'s smart pointers. In fact, the programmer _doesn't_ specify when and where an object is to be destroyed: C++'s scoping rules do.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit:  That same article also says, " In languages that do not have built in garbage collection, [...] as with the Boehm garbage collector for C and C++. "  So wiki is simultaneously saying that C++ is and is not garbage collected.  The moral of this story is that wiki is not the ultimate reference.

Comment: @JohnDibling: ... hence my link to the peer-reviewed scientific journals. You introduced Wikipedia article text as citation.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit:  Help me out a bit here.  Which article specifically says that C++ smart pointers are a form of garbage collection?

Comment: @JohnDibling: Garbage collection in C++ is not built-in.  It's provided by libraries, including the standard library.  The two claims are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: @user1824407 - Re *also i can't see the point of this design where shared_ptr are inside the object and there are 2 different shared_ptr per object* This is a contrived example, and that's a good thing. We don't want people to post all of their code. We want them to provide a minimal working example. That's what this code is.

Comment: @JohnDibling: They present a wider definition of the term into which `std::shared_ptr` easily falls; it is this definition on which the text of the article you cited relies. The definition of a term is always going to be subjective but I don't think there's grounds to simply assert that "there is no garbage collection in C++"; that's all.

Comment: @JohnDibling In his example, `std::shared_ptr` is being used for garbage collection.

Comment: And true garbage collection does exist in C++.  It's just not standard.

Comment: @James: By "true GC", you mean a mark-and-sweep reachability analysis?

Comment: @JohnDibling The whole point of using `shared_ptr` (usually) is that I don't have to explicitly specify when an object should be deallocated.  That's garbage collection.  It's not a very effective form of garbage collection, so we usually avoid it, and prefer other solutions (such as the Boehm collector) when possible.

Comment: @BenVoigt Or other algorithms which handle cycles, etc., correctly.  Mark and sweep is the simplest and best known, but it is not the only one.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Fair enough.  Those articles provide their own definition of "garbage collection," which you choose to accept.  I don't, because GC has traditionally meant the presence of a garbage collector running behind the scenes, beyond the reach of the programmer.  The RAII idiom falls outside that definition.  Since "garbage collected" is not a standardized term with universal, specific definition, nobody can ever be right or wrong here.

Comment: @johndibling imagine C++ gets compile time reflection.  Now we can implement `mark_and_sweep` smart pointers.  Are they gc?

Comment: Lightness & John: I know you're both smart enough to know you shouldn't be arguing over the definition of words without some authoritative context. Some definitions of GC support one side, and others support other sides. Neither is "right" in a vacuum. What's important is: does it solve any problems if one of you is right? I don't think it matters at this point. John was probably worried about a passerby reading "C++" & "GC" together in a sentence and concluding `new int;` doesn't leak, while Lightness is noting that this distinction isn't useful to someone who knows C++. Oh well.

Answer (score 8):

This isn't usually a problem, because normally you keep a tree balanced and the depth is O(lg N).

You've instead got a weird singly-linked list, with a duplicate copy of every pointer.  That's... odd.

A real singly-linked list would be very deep recursion, but might benefit from tail call optimization and not exhaust the stack.

The problem you're having is really quite unique to your mixing of the two data structures.  Which has no benefits that I can see.

Comment: how you can prove that this is O(lg N) ? You can't even say how shared_ptr is implemented ? the implementation of a shared_ptr it's not standard ...

Comment: This is a simplified version of a more complex problem.  It was the shortest code that I could come up with that exhibits the problem.  Sorry for the oddity.

Comment: @user1824407: The depth of a balanced tree has nothing to do with the implementation of `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: really ? so the internal management of a shared_ptr is magic ? your CPU will spend no time updating and manipulating the state of a shared_ptr ?

Comment: @user1824407: I'm not talking about time or space complexity of the implementation of some operation that iterates the entire tree, I'm talking about **depth of the tree**.  Any balanced tree data structure has O(lg N) **depth**.  If your data structure doesn't, it is not a balanced tree.

Comment: and what the depth has to do with this kind of problem ? we are not designing a data structure, it's a runtime problem ...

Comment: @user1824407: Well, now we get to the implementation of deletion of the tree (which I believe most people understand implicitly).  Which is O(f(N)) time complexity but O(f(depth)) space complexity.  And those complexity limits can be derived by the fact that each `shared_ptr` is aware of a limited number of other `shared_ptr` instances.

Comment: @user1824407: But the reason I keep bringing up **depth** is because that is the part of my answer you commented on.

Comment: @user1824407 The problem is the ratio between stack space and total memory. On most usage patterns, even an unbalanced tree will run out of total memory long before destruction of the tree runs out of stack memory. Only by constructing a maximum depth (unbalanced) tree, the stack space shortage can be triggered. Therefor mentioning the depth of the tree is totally reasonable.

Answer (score 4):

Your assessment looks totally correct to me. It looks like the recursive calls to delete child subtrees are exceeding yoru stack size. This is unrelated to `shared_ptr` though as I would expect any recursive algorithms on the data structure to also fail in the same way.

If possible on your platform, the simplest way to deal with the need for large structures like that is simply to increase the size of your stack (for example `ulimit`) to allow the natural recursive algorithm to function.

If that's not possible you're going to have to traverse the nodes yourself, storing the result of the traversal into a container of some sort so you can chop of subnodes and not require a full depth traversal of the tree structure.

Comment: I think that it's important to note that the definition of a shared_ptr it's templated and its actual implementation is different among compilers and platforms. the words on shared_ptr from the official C++ standard are about functionalities that shared_ptr provides, not about implementation details.

Comment: @user1824407: You're correct and I think that's part of the problem in this situation.  As far as I know, there's nothing in the standard that says that the deallocation will use a recursive algorithm to free the memory.  All the same, since that's a possibility and causing the segfault in this case, I need some strategies for compensating.

Comment: @wyer33 The standard guarantees the order of destruction. The leaf nodes have to be destructed before the intermediate nodes. Without a parent pointer, it's impossible to do so without storing the list of nodes to be deleted somewhere. A recursive implementation stores the list on the call stack.

Comment: @wyer33 Now imagine that the leaf nodes are shared but the intermediate nodes are not (not a real tree, but OP's tree is not a tree either). Or there could be polymorphism: when the destructor is virtual, it is impossible to build that list-of-nodes-to-be-destructed without calling the destructor.

Comment: @wyer33 The actual implementation of `std::shared_ptr` is implementation dependent, but there are a number of constraints.  In particular, it must call the destructor of the object, and if the object contains `shared_ptr`, then the destructor of the object must call the destructor on those.  A single instance of `shared_ptr` can only handle a single object.  So in his case, it must be recursive.  In the abstract machine, at least; there's no restriction as to what the compiler can do under the "as if" rule.

Answer (score 1):

This looks to me like a misuse of `std::shared_ptr`.  And some
very poor naming: your class `MyTree` isn't a tree, but simply
a node.  The tree should be a separate class, and should delete
all of the nodes in its destructor.

Having said that, this won't change much with regards to the
problem at hand.  You're visiting the nodes on the tree
recursively (about the only way that makes sense), and if you
let the tree get too deep, the stack will overflow, regardless
of whether the visiting is implicit (through the destructor
calls in `std::shared_ptr`) or explicit.  Creating such trees to
begin with makes no sense, since there's no point in creating
a tree whose nodes you cannot visit *before* you start
destructing it.

### EDIT:

To take into account the discussion of garbage collection in the comments.
Using the Boehm collector, or some other garbage collector, will solve the 
problem of deallocating the elements.  But it still won't allow you to visit
them before deallocation, so such a tree remains useless.  (I think that there
are very strong arguments in favor of garbage collection in C++, but this isn't
one of them.)

Answer (score 0):

I think this type of error can reproduced without shared_ptr. This is basically a long recursion call. Ok, I just created and deleted half of the tree but...

```
struct MyTree {
    MyTree *left;
    int val;
    MyTree()
    {
      left = 0;
    }
    MyTree(MyTree *left_)
     : left(left_) {};

    ~MyTree()
    {
      delete left;
    }
};
int main() {
    MyTree *t = new MyTree();
    for(int i=0;i<100000;i++) {
      t = new MyTree(t);
    }
    delete t;
}
```

Just add one more zero after 100000 and you got the same error message