# Stack overflow with unique_ptr linked list

Tags: c++, c++11, linked-list, stack-overflow, unique-ptr

I've converted the following linked list struct

```
struct node {
  node* next;
  int v;
};
```

into a c++11 version - that is not using the pointers.

```
struct node {
  unique_ptr<node> next;
  int v;
};
```

Adding, removing elements and traversing works fine, however when I insert roughly 1mil elements, I get a stack overflow when when the destructor of the head node is called.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
{
  node n;

  ... add 10mill elements

} <-- crash here
```

Comment: `... add 10mill elements` at the stack?? Provide a [MCVE] please.

Comment: isn't memory unique_ptr manages can be on heap?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168821/stdunique-ptr-as-pointer-in-a-node-based-structure

Comment: What does your destructor look like? If you don't have one, as your code above suggests, then it can't possibly work correctly. You need code to iterate over the linked list and delete from the end back.

Comment: atMat so the destructor must have codes to delete the next iteratively? i was hope to rely with RAII not think about such details

Comment: atDavid, currently no user coded destructor, just compiler made destructor

Comment: @HappyKoding Think about how that would work. To delete the first node, you first need to delete the second node, so you call a function. But to do that, you first need to delete the third node. So you call a function. You would have millions of levels of function invocation. There's a specific way you need to unravel that linked list, and if you don't write the code to do it, it will **not** write itself.

Comment: atDavid yes i agree I had hoped modern C++ would make such details go away, but think i need to write the codes like old styles

Comment: @DavidSchwartz  There's no need to write that yourself, the `unique_ptr` destructor does it automatically.

Comment: @zenith It can't do that. It has no idea that the object is part of a linked list and that therefore a special algorithm is needed to make the destruction sane. It's just going to run the default destructor for the object, which is going to run the default destructor for the pointed to object and so on. That's an insane algorithm for this particular problem.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz It's insane only from a performance point of view.

Comment: @zenith It's not just insane from a performance point of view, it's insane from a "can I reasonably expect it to work on an actual computer" point of view. And, in fact, it didn't work.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As explained in the other answers, you segfault because of the recursive implicit destructor. It is possible to fix this without resorting to raw pointers, having to trust the compiler or writing a custom allocator:

```
~node() {
    for (std::unique_ptr<node> current = std::move(next);
         current;
         current = std::move(current->next));
}
```

Here you iteratively go through the chain of pointers. This will, one at a time, unchain one pointer and change ownership `std::move(current->next)` to current. At the same time the previous unchained pointer, owned by `current`, will be released while being overwritten by the move assignment.

You may find the explicit variant more straightforward:

```
current.reset(current->next.release()));
```

Is effectively the same as:

```
current = std::move(current->next));
```

I prefer the `move` version, because it does at no time leave you with a raw pointer. But in that case it does not make a difference.

Answer (score 11):

You are making nothing wrong here.

When you create your list of 10 millions elements, allocation each node with `make_unique` everything is fine (Of course the data is not on the stack, except perhaps the first node !).

The problem is when you you get rid of the head of your list:  `unique_ptr` will take care of the deleting the next node that it owns, which also contains a `unique_ptr` that will take care of deleting the next node... etc...

So that in the end the 10 millions elements get deleted recursively, each recursive call taking some space on the stack.

Comment: is there way to get round this problem or should go back to raw pointer?

Comment: yes, there's a way round:  when you create the unique_ptr you can provide a custom deleter that will be invoked instead of the default deleter.  So you could provide one that makes the deleting iterative instead of recursive.

Comment: You had a destructor before right? And it implemented a sane algorithm that iteratively destroyed the list. Put that code back or where will sane deletion come from? It takes an iterative algorithm to destroy this linked list sanely.

Comment: Compiling with `-O2` might optimize such reccursion.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz you are of course right: replacing the default deleter with a custom one that iterates through the list to reset the pointers takes a little bit of the benefit of the unique_ptr, and will look pretty close to the code that you'd write without unique_ptr.   The main remaining advantage would be to make the ownership of the nodes explicit. I think OP's question is of educational/experimental purpose, as in the real world we 'd all use `<list>`

Comment: @Zereges that's an excellent suggestion ! If HappyCoding could try this workaround, it would be very interesting to let us know if it solves the problem.

Comment: atZereges: I tried O2 with gcc and clang. clang is not crashing now but gcc is still crashing. gcc is 4.9 clang is 3.5

Answer (score 7):

By default `std::unique_ptr` calls the operator function of structure `std::default_delete` that just executes operator `delete`.

So each operator function of the structure `std::default_delete` recursively calls itself for data member `next` of structure `node`.

As result you get the stack overflow.

You would get the same result if you used ordinary pointers instead of the pointers of type `std::unique_ptr` but added a destructor to the structure node the following way

```
struct node {
  node* next;
  int v;
  ~node() { delete next; } 
};
```

Or even like

```
struct node {
  node* next;
  int v;
  ~node() { if ( next ) delete next; } 
};
```

for a list with a big number of nodes because the destructor will be called recursively

Comment: yes your right, was hope to not have to deal with details and rely on RAII concept

Comment: `if (next) delete next` is redundant because deleting a null pointer has no effect.

Comment: @zenith I meant that if even he will write such a way there will be changed nothing.

Answer (score 3):

Because when you destroy the head node element, it calls destructor oа unique_ptr, which destroys the second element that calls destructor of the 3rd element which calls ... etс 1mil  times.

So, you have 1 mil nested funtion calls (of destructors). Each function call takes memory in stack at least to store return address (and parameters and local variables as well, if needed). Naturally, stack can not provide such amount of memory. You should redesing code to resolve it. For instance, rewrite destructor of Node class so that it finds the last list element and then destroys it and all other nodes from the end in a cicle, not recursievely.