# unique_ptr: linked list entry deletion

Tags: c++, linked-list, undefined-behavior, unique-ptr

I am currently considering the implementation of a single linked list with the aid of unique_ptrs. Despite the problem of a possible stack overflow due to the recursive call of the destructors (see [Stack overflow with unique_ptr linked list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35535312/stack-overflow-with-unique-ptr-linked-list)), I came across the following problem: 
Assume, we have the following implementation of the linked list

```
struct node {
  node (void) : val(0), next(nullptr) {}
  int val;
  std::unique_ptr<node> next;
};
```

and we have initialized our list according to

```
int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
  node HEAD;
  HEAD.val = 0;
  auto ptr = &HEAD;
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    ptr->val = i;
    ptr->next.reset(new node);
    ptr = ptr->next.get();
  }
  ptr->val = 10;
  ...
```

Now, I would like to delete the node with the value 1:

```
ptr = &HEAD;
ptr = ptr->next.get();
HEAD.next = std::move(ptr->next);
```

At first glance, this seems  sensible. Still, I am not sure if it might cause undefined behaviour:

According to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator%3D, the
operator=

> Transfers ownership from r to *this as if by calling reset(r.release()) 
>   followed by an assignment of get_deleter() from std::forward
>   (r.get_deleter())

Having a closer look at unique_ptr::reset (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/reset), it reads

> Given current_ptr, the pointer that was managed by *this, performs the
>   following actions, in this order:
>
> 1. Saves a copy of the current pointer old_ptr = current_ptr
> 2. Overwrites the current pointer with the argument current_ptr = ptr
> 3. If the old pointer was non-empty, deletes the previously managed object 
>      if(old_ptr != nullptr) get_deleter()(old_ptr)

This means that in this case the call of r.get_deleter() would reference an object that has already been destroyed, or am I mistaken here?

Thank you very much for your responses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your concerns seem valid to me. The ptr->next.get_deleter() no longer exists, because `ptr->next` is destroyed (although no longer owning anything) along with `*ptr` when `ptr` is reset. In most cases it's probably not going to matter, since the deleter is going to be an empty base class, and assignment is going to be a no-op, but still technically undefined behaviour.

I'd go with `HEAD.next.reset(ptr->next.release());` explicitly (if you don't care about the deleter), or `HEAD.next = std::unique_ptr<node>(std::move(ptr->next))` if you are concerned about preserving the deleter.

Comment: Upvoted but a potential problem with this approach is that the deleter associated with the second node has been lost. If you don't have a stateful deleter then that is not a problem but I suspect OPs approach works in that case anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are correct.

The only thing preventing the `HEAD.next->next` `unique_ptr` being destroyed is that `HEAD.next` `node` holds it. The act of assigning to `HEAD.next` breaks that *before* trying to get the deleter from `HEAD.next->next` `unique_ptr`.

To me, the intuitive way of deleting the node with value 1 would be to detach the tail from the head and then re-attach the tail from the node with value 2:

```
auto tail = std::move(HEAD.next);
HEAD.next = std::move(tail.next);
```

What you are trying to do is like cutting and re-attaching a snake while only holding the snake with one hand, if you are not careful bits of the snake might wriggle away.

**Edit:**  I tried using a stateful deleter like this:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

struct node;

class NodeDeleter {
  int deleterNumber;
public:
  NodeDeleter() : deleterNumber(-1) {}
  NodeDeleter(int deleterNumber) : deleterNumber(deleterNumber) {}
  void operator()(node* n);
};

struct node {
  node() : val(0), next(nullptr) {}
  int val;
  std::unique_ptr<node, NodeDeleter> next;
};

void NodeDeleter::operator()(node* n) {
  std::cout << "Deleting node with value " << n->val << " using deleter " << deleterNumber << "\n";
  delete n;
}

std::unique_ptr<node, NodeDeleter> make_node(int deleterNumber) {
  return std::unique_ptr<node, NodeDeleter>(new node(), NodeDeleter(deleterNumber));
}

int main() {
  node HEAD;
  HEAD.val = 0;
  auto ptr = &HEAD;
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    ptr->val = i;
    ptr->next = make_node(i);
    ptr = ptr->next.get();
  }
  ptr->val = 10;

  HEAD.next = std::move(HEAD.next->next);
}
```

Interestingly, in GCC it seems to behave itself but in Visual Studio 2015 it is clearly invoking undefined behaviour. The output is:

```
Deleting node with value 1 using deleter 0
Deleting node with value 2 using deleter -572662307
Deleting node with value 3 using deleter 2
Deleting node with value 4 using deleter 3
...
```

It looks like it is trying to use deleter 1 after it has been destroyed.

Comment: I think this as well as the answer from @JosephIreland may resolve the problem. In particular, I agree on your image of cutting and re-attaching a snake :)

Comment: Have you tried to add a print in your `NodeDeleter` destructor? It's interesting (I'm using gcc btw).

Comment: @FranMowinckel I did but there is so much constructing, copying and assigning of deleters going on there is a lot of spurious calls to the destructor (http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/5fl4EKiednA6m0rU). I think if you keep track of them all you can see it deleting the last copy before it uses it.

Comment: @ChrisDrew I mean at the end, nodes are being deleted in order but deleters are being *deleted* in reverse order and after the nodes have been deleted. I find it interesting. BTW I've also tested in VC++ but depending on the version it works or not.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you're mistaken because when you *move* the pointer (`std::move`) you're generating a rvalue and leaving `ptr->next` in a *released* state so it's not an undefined behaviour.

I mean, prior to `reset` you're releasing the pointer: `reset(r.release())`

And then:

```
HEAD.next = std::move(HEAD.next->next);
```

Edit after comments (just adding the code I was testing):

```
struct custom_deleter {  // a deleter class with state
  custom_deleter() {}
  ~custom_deleter() {
    std::cout << "custom deleter deleted" << std::endl;
 }
  template <class T>
  void operator()(T* p) {
    std::cout << "custom deleter()" << std::endl;
    delete p;
  }
};

struct node {
  node (void) : val(0), next(nullptr) {}
  ~node () {
    std::cout << "~node " << val << std::endl;
  }
  int val;
  std::unique_ptr<node, custom_deleter> next;
};

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
  node HEAD;
  HEAD.val = 0;
  auto ptr = &HEAD;
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    ptr->val = i;
    ptr->next.reset(new node);
    ptr = ptr->next.get();
  }
  ptr->val = 10;

  std::cout << "And now we delete it" << std::endl;
  HEAD.next = std::move(HEAD.next->next);

  std::cout << "Looping" << std::endl;
  ptr = &HEAD;
  for (int i=0; i < 9; ++i) {
      std::cout << ptr->val << std::endl;
      ptr = ptr->next.get();
  }
  std::cout << "End." << std::endl;
}
```

And results:

```
custom deleter()
~node 1
custom deleter deleted
Looping
0
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
End.
~node 0
custom deleter()
~node 2
custom deleter()
~node 3
custom deleter()
~node 4
custom deleter()
~node 5
custom deleter()
~node 6
custom deleter()
~node 7
custom deleter()
~node 8
custom deleter()
~node 9
custom deleter()
~node 10
custom deleter deleted
custom deleter deleted
custom deleter deleted
custom deleter deleted
custom deleter deleted
custom deleter deleted
custom deleter deleted
custom deleter deleted
custom deleter deleted
custom deleter deleted
```

Comment: I think the point is that the only thing preventing the `unique_ptr` `HEAD.next->next` being destroyed is that `HEAD.next` holds it. The act of assigning to `HEAD.next` breaks that *before* trying to get the deleter from `HEAD.next->next`.

Comment: @ChrisDrew `HEAD.next->next` indeed gets destroyed, but it was released before, so its *content* it's not. I have tested (quickly) the code, and it works fine.

Comment: It's not the content of the `unique_ptr` that OP is worried about.  It is the deleter in the `unique_ptr`.

Comment: @ChrisDrew still it's not destroyed. I consider the deleter to be a part of its contents. I'll update my answer to show it.

Comment: See my answer, I've tried it with a stateful deleter and can  indeed invoke undefined behviour on VS2015.

Comment: @ChrisDrew vc++ 19.10.24631.0 (x86) testing with your code gives that undefined behaviour, but vc++ 19.00.23506 (x86) works fine, so... could it be a bug? I mean I've tested in various compilers and works fine.

Comment: I don't think it is a bug. One of the ways undefined behaviour can manifest itself is in "working fine" that doesn't mean it isn't undefined behaviour.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129685/discussion-between-franmowinckel-and-chris-drew).