# Using shared_ptr for linked_list gives stackoverflow within destructor

Tags: c++, linked-list, stack-overflow, shared-ptr

I'm trying to implement a linked list using shared_ptr rather than raw pointers. The code :

```
#include <memory>
class NodeTest
{
private:
    int v;
    std::shared_ptr<NodeTest> next;
public:
    NodeTest() { v = 0; };
    NodeTest(unsigned int i) { v = i; }
    ~NodeTest() {};
    void setNext(std::shared_ptr<NodeTest> & toSet) { next = toSet; }
};

std::shared_ptr<NodeTest> init()
{
    std::shared_ptr<NodeTest> elt = std::shared_ptr<NodeTest>(new NodeTest());
    std::shared_ptr<NodeTest> first = elt;
    for (unsigned int i = 1; i < 5000; i++)
    {
        std::shared_ptr<NodeTest> next(new NodeTest(i));
        elt->setNext(next);
        elt = next;
    }
    return first;
}

void test_destroy()
{
    std::shared_ptr<NodeTest> aList = init();
}


int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    test_destroy();
}
```

This is generating a stackoverflow when leaving `test_destroy()` scope because of the call to `aList` destructor (RAII). To destroy `aList`, it calls the destructor of `next` and so on, which obviously ends up with a stackoverflow for a sufficiently large list.

I can't find any efficient way to fix this. The ideal case would be to delete the current `NodeTest` before moving to `next` deletion, right? How would you do such a thing?

Thanks in advance

**Solution :** You need to break the links between all nodes AND save a pointer to each node so that the destructor is not immediatly called upon breaking links. Example below using a vector.

```
~NodeTest() 
{
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<NodeTest>> buffer;
    std::shared_ptr<NodeTest> cursor = next;

    while (cursor.use_count()!=0)
    {
        std::shared_ptr<NodeTest> temp = cursor->getNext();
        cursor->setNext(std::shared_ptr<NodeTest>());
        buffer.push_back(cursor);
        cursor = temp;
    }

    next = std::shared_ptr<NodeTest>();
};
```

Comment: transpose the list of nodes into a vector and then delete the vector?

Comment: I want to achieve this with a linked list because of my practical case. I need to be able to insert in head and queue in a two dimensional matrix with O(1) (basically to stack two matrices as [E] = [A][B] for example).

Comment: Wait, you mean `push_backing` all nodes in a vector so that I have at least `use_count() >1`, then delete elements in the linked list, then delete the vector?

Comment: no, `std::move()` them in

Comment: Find a C++ compiler that does proper tail calls? use `std::forward_list` instead?

Comment: The second answer in [Stack overflow with unique\_ptr linked list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35535312/stack-overflow-with-unique-ptr-linked-list) provides a solution.

Comment: Yeah this is the way given in the video @Alex shared. I made a solution with vector, adding it to OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you should manage nodes deleting manually because destructor calls destructor calls destructor .....

Take a look on the talk [CppCon 2016: Herb Sutter “Leak-Freedom in C++... By Default.”](https://youtu.be/JfmTagWcqoE?t=795)

Comment: Thanks for sharing, checking it.

Answer (score 0):

The destructor of `NodeTest` invokes the destructor of `NodeTest::next` which recursively calls another `NodeTest` destructor and so on until the stack is exhausted. Smart-pointers should not be used for linking nodes for this reason.